# Automatic / templated generation of test vectors in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, metaprogramming

I want to find a good way to generate test vectors automatically.  By way of example, I am testing an audio processing module by calling a function that exercises the module-under-test with the specified test vector and in doing so makes various checks for proper operation and correctness of module output.

```
void runTest(const char *source, double gain, int level);
```

The test vector is the triplet of `source`, `gain` and `level`.  Here is the multidimensional space I want to test against:

```
const char *sources[] = {"guitar.mp3", "vocals.mp3", "drums.mp3"};
double gains[] = {1., 10., 100.};
int levels[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Values can have other properties, for example if vocals.mp3 has a dynamic rage of 2, guitar 5 and drums 10, we could conceive a representation like:

```
int dynamicRange(const char *source);
```

I want to be able to configure various test runs.  For example, I want to be able to run:

```
// all permutations (total 36 vectors)
runTest("guitar.mp3", 1., 1);
runTest("guitar.mp3", 1., 2);
runTest("guitar.mp3", 1., 3);
runTest("guitar.mp3", 1., 4);
runTest("guitar.mp3", 1., 1);
runTest("guitar.mp3", 10., 2);
runTest("guitar.mp3", 10., 3);
// ...

// corner cases (according to dynamicRange)
runTest("vocals.mp3", 1., 1);
runTest("vocals.mp3", 1., 4);
runTest("vocals.mp3", 100., 1);
runTest("vocals.mp3", 100., 4);
runTest("drums.mp3", 1., 1);
runTest("drums.mp3", 1., 4);
runTest("drums.mp3", 100., 1);
runTest("drums.mp3", 100., 4);

// sparse / minimal tests touching every value for each parameter
runTest("guitar.mp3", 1., 1);  
runTest("vocals.mp3", 10., 2);  
runTest("drums.mp3", 100., 3);  
runTest("guitar.mp3", 1., 4);  

// quick test
runTest("guitar.mp3", 1., 1);
```

I want create the above code without lots of copy and paste either dynamically or using my compiler to do the legwork, for example:

```
// syntax tentative here, could be class/template instantiations
allPermutations(runTest, sources, gains, levels);
cornerCases(runTest, lookup(sources, dynamicRange), gains, levels);
minimal(runTest, sources, gains, levels);
quick(runTest, sources, gains, levels);
```

The above looks like dynamic C but my language is C++ and I am expecting to use templates and some combination of dynamic and static techniques.  Perhaps even metaprogramming.

Combinations and variations would also be interesting.  For example, I might want to use only the shortest input file.  Or I might want to run all sources with corner-cases for `gain` and `level`.  Or `gain` could also be a continuous range 1 to 100 but let's keep things discrete for now.

Before I start designing types, templates, representation, etc. I wondered if this is a problem that has been solved before or, if not, would any existing libraries, e.g. Boost MPL, be useful?

Comment: Why do you want templates ? Aren't nested for loops enough ?

Comment: I don't necessarily need templates but I only want to write "allPermutations", "cornerCases", "minimal", "allPairs", etc. once to cope with any number of dimensions and all parameter types.

Comment: Ok, I missed this. The best way is probably to use a common interface based on eg. `boost::any` for passing test parameters. This way, you separate the sheduling and parameters allocation from the tests themselves. In this respect, @Alexander Poluektov's solution seems flexible enough if you don't want to use a particular framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was very tempting to think a bit about this very programmer-friendly task :)

Here I came with dynamic solution using boost::any as the medium to store "erased" types in.
More static solution would use probably Boost.Tuple and Boost.Fusion/Boost.MPL indeed, but I'm not sure it is worth the trouble.

The code is prototype-quality, and for sure you are not going to use it as it is. But at least it can give you direction.

So the mini-framework:

```
typedef boost::option<boost::any> OptionalValue;
OptionalValue const no_value;

// represents each dimension from your multi-dimensional solution
struct Emitter
{
    virtual ~Emitter() { }

    // should return no_value to indicate that emitting finished
    virtual OptionalValue emit() = 0;
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Emitter> EmitterPtr;

// generates test vectors according to passed emitters and run test function on each
class Generator
{
public:

    void add_emitter(EmitterPtr p) { emitters.push_back(p); }

    // here f is callback called for each test vector
    // could call test, or could store test vector in some container
    template <class F>
    void run(F f)
    {
        std::vector<boost::any> v;
        generate(v, 0, f);
    }

private:

    template <class F>
    void generate(vector<boost::any>& v, size_t i, F f)
    {
        if (i == emitters.size())
        {
            f(v);
        }

        EmitterPtr e = emitters[i];
        for (OptionalValue val = e->emit(); val; )
        {
            v.push_back(*val);
            generate(v, i + 1, f);
            v.pop_back();
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<EmitterPtr> emitters;
};
```

Some concrete emitters:

```
// emits all values from given range
template <class FwdIt>
struct EmitAll : Emitter
{
    EmitAll(FwdIt begin, FwdIt end) : current(begin), end(end) { }
    OptionalValue emit() { return current == end ? no_value : *(current++); }

    FwdIt current;
    FwdIt const end;
};

// emits first value from given range, and finshes work
template <class FwdIt>
struct EmitFirst : Emitter
{
    EmitFirst(FwdIt begin, FwdIt) : current(begin), n(0) { }
    OptionalValue emit() { return n++ == 0 ? *current : no_value; }

    FwdIt current;
    size_t n;
};

// emits only values satisfied predicate P
template <class FwdIt, class P>
struct EmitFiltered
{
    EmitFiltered(FwdIt begin, FwdIt end) : current(begin), end(end) { }
    OptionalValue emit()
    {
        P const p;
        while (current != end)
        {
            if (!p(current)) continue;
            return *(current++);
        }
        return no_value;
    }

    FwdIt current;
    FwdIt const end;
};

// helpers for automatic types' deducing
template <class FwdIt>
EmitterPtr make_emit_all(FwdIt b, Fwd e) { return new EmitAll<FwdIt>(b, e); }

template <class FwdIt>
EmitterPtr make_emit_first(FwdIt b, Fwd e) { return EmitFirst<FwdIt>(b, e); }

template <class FwdIt>
EmitterPtr make_emit_filtered(FwdIt b, Fwd e, P p) { return EmitFiltered<FwdIt, P>(b, e, p); }
```

Adapter for runTest:

```
struct Run
{
    void operator()(const std::vector<boost::any>& v)
    {
        assert v.size() == 3;
        runTest(boost::any_cast<std::string>(v[0]),
                boost::any_cast<double>     (v[1]),
                boost::any_cast<int>        (v[2]));
    }
};
```

Finally usage:

```
Generator all_permutations;
all_permutations.add_emitter(make_emit_all(sources, sources + 3));
all_permutations.add_emitter(make_emit_all(gains,   gains + 3));
all_permutations.add_emitter(make_emit_all(levels,  levels + 4));

Generator quick;
quick.add_emitter(make_emit_first(sources, sources + 3));
quick.add_emitter(make_emit_first(gains,   gains + 3));
quick.add_emitter(make_emit_first(levels,  levels + 4));

Generator corner_cases;
corner_cases.add_emitter(make_emit_all(sources, sources + 3));
corner_cases.add_emitter(make_emit_filtered(gains, gains + 3, LookupDynamicRange));
corner_cases.add_emitter(make_emit_all(levels,  levels + 4));

Run r;
all_permutations.run(r);
quick.run(r);
corner_cases(r);
```

Implementing all-pairs beast (for 'minimal' guy) is left to you to implement %)

Comment: Looks nice, thanks!.  Will try this later.  Have not used boost::any before.

Comment: Thanks for marking my answer. But know I think that having "iterator" concept rather than "emitter" would be more appropriate: you need `reset()` method in Emitter class anyway, so why not just give concepts and operations good idiomatic names instead (iterator, begin, end, ++). Anyway I've debugged the code I'd posted, so if you are interested in fixes, drop a line here.

Comment: I agree iterator makes more sense and having looked deeper into this, perhaps even the Boost "range" concept is better.  This allows range operations on the input data sets which is pretty powerful and means I only need a handful of "generators" operating over the multidimensional space: exhaustive, all-values, all-pairs.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be useful if you introduce yourself to concept of [All-pairs testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing), and have a quick check for [QuickCheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_check) (it is the Haskell test framework which generates test cases randomly according to the given spec, and then checks that some properties are hold; there exists [C++ version of it](http://software.legiasoft.com/quickcheck/)).

Regarding Boost.MPL in particular, I don't think it would help you for this task at all: you are not dealing with list of types here, are you.

My another advise on your upcoming design: don't overgeneralize.
Before you start with types, templates, etc. implement 3 (three) reasonably different implementations, and then generalize what you already have at hand.

Comment: Re. list of types - that is exactly what I am dealing with, isn't it?   Each parameter could be a different type and there could be any number of them.  All-pairs testing looks like an interesting weapon to add to Exhaustive, Corner-cases, etc.

Comment: I would rather use here more dynamic solution than list of types. Would post some code soon.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [Template2Code](http://template2code.sourceforge.net/) framework. It is especially designed for solving your problem. The comprehensive documentation is [here](http://template2code.sourceforge.net/t2c-doc/). According to the documentation you should create a [*.t2c file](http://template2code.sourceforge.net/t2c-doc/t2c_file.html) of the following structure to generate a complete set of test vectors:

```
<BLOCK>
    ...
    <DEFINE>
        #define SOURCE <%0%>
        #define GAIN <%1%>
        #define LEVEL <%2%>
    </DEFINE>
    <CODE>
        runTest(SOURCES, GAINS, LEVELS);
    </CODE>
    <VALUES>
        SET("guitar.mp3"; "vocals.mp3"; "drums.mp3")
        SET(1.; 10.; 100.)
        SET(1; 2; 3; 4)
    </VALUES>
    ...
</BLOCK>
```

This technology was used by [The Linux Foundation](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/) and [ISPRAS](http://ispras.linuxfoundation.org/) to create ["normal"-quality tests](http://ispras.linuxfoundation.org/index.php/LSB_Normal_Tests) for libstdcxx, glib, gtk, fontconfig, freetype and other libraries.